# Realtime SCART input with audio on an iMac

Tags: mac, audio, imac, video

I was just wondering if there's any hardware I could purchase which would allow me to basically use my iMac as a television, for analogue signals mainly as I can already watch digital content on it without issue.

It'd be mainly for watching VHS, over SCART, so the hardware solution would ideally allow synchronised audio, as well as full screen display. A small amount of latency wouldn't be an issue really.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For cheap & cheerful, maybe something like this - http://www.amazon.co.uk/ClimaxDigital-VCAP800-Capture-Mavericks-Mountain/dp/B00466VIB4

I've never tried it myself, so I've nothing to go on other than the reviews, which seem varied.